# How can I export all my Iphone's data from the backup data into a useable format?

Tags: iphone, backup, data

I am switching from my iphone after many years to a pinephone. **I would like to be able to use or access the data, notes, files, sms, images, voice memos, contacts and so on.**

I don't need to worry about the data being set up on the new phone. I just want to make sure I can access and use the data before I let go of my iphone.

I would also like some assurance that any third party program isn't uploading whatever they can get to their own servers to their own ends. Via paying for the software or auditable open source software.

Lastly I want to be as thorough as possible in not leaving anything out.

Any suggestion of tools or knowledge about how the backup data is stored or could be exported that could lens insight into a solution is appreciated.

Comment: There are apps available (iMazing, iExplorer) that work with iOS device backups, you may want to investigate them.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of phone apps store their data in a way that no other software can read. Your best option is often to use the app on your phone to somehow export the data - instead of working with backups.

A lot of the Files app can be accessed via iCloud Drive or copied into dropbox/etc. Photos can be exported by connecting your phone to a computer and importing it like you would a DSLR camera. Contacts can be synced with various PC contact apps, and from there exported as vcard files.

Some apps won't have good export options and it might be easier to just give up on that data.

Some apps, especially music and video players, have DRM specifically designed to enforce contract license terms that do not allow exporting. In the case of Apple music, the contract terms and DRM differ depending wether you downloaded the song as a "subscriber" or "purchased" the song.

Please try searching for existing questions/answers for each individual app with data you'd like to archive, and if you can't find anything, ask a separate question for each one.

Comment: Good answer I think. It makes me wonder also... why doesn't Apple make "open data stores" a requirement for apps in the AppStore? Oh right... [all that talk about privacy](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2019/01/apples-hypocritical-defense-data-privacy/581680/), and being open with customers about the [personal data Apple holds](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/talkingtech/2018/04/17/apple-make-simpler-download-your-privacy-data-year/521786002/) is actually **bunkum**. Apple seems to believe **you don't own your own personal data**.

Comment: @Seamus your comment is off topic and also demonstrably false. Apple virtually always uses open data formats like sqlite and zip or works with industry standards committees to invent new formats (HEIF for example), and accessing the data is usually simple with their apps. And they encourage third party developers to do the same. It's just that many third party developers choose not to, and it would be draconian for Apple to force them into it.

Comment: Respectfully, but strongly, disagree.